# WPF popup window

Tags: c#, wpf

I would like to let the user choose their options after a button is clicked. For example, showing two buttons, "Restart Now" and "Restart Later" in a modal popup window would be my preference. Using a `MessageBox` is not a solution for me as it does not allow the user to change the title of buttons.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You need to create a new Window class. You can design that then any way you want. You can create and show a window modally like this:

```
MyWindow popup = new MyWindow();
popup.ShowDialog();
```

You can add a custom property for your result value, or if you only have two possible results ( + possibly undeterminate, which would be `null`), you can set the window's [`DialogResult`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.dialogresult.aspx) property  before closing it and then check for it (it is the value returned by `ShowDialog()`).

Comment: +1, though would be useful to briefly mention the IsDefault and IsCancel button properties as well, as described in the DialogResult link.

Answer (score 27):

In WPF there is a control named Popup.

```
Popup myPopup = new Popup();
//(...)
myPopup.IsOpen = true;
```

Comment: Why -1? Could u explain?:)

Comment: I can't get this code to work. Do you know why it won't recognise Popup?

Comment: Here's the class reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.popup(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Seems to be more appropriate for tooltips than dialog windows

Answer (score 6):

XAML

```
<Popup Name="myPopup">
      <TextBlock Name="myPopupText" 
                 Background="LightBlue" 
                 Foreground="Blue">
        Popup Text
      </TextBlock>
</Popup>
```

c#

```
    Popup codePopup = new Popup();
    TextBlock popupText = new TextBlock();
    popupText.Text = "Popup Text";
    popupText.Background = Brushes.LightBlue;
    popupText.Foreground = Brushes.Blue;
    codePopup.Child = popupText;
```

you can find more details about the Popup Control from MSDN documentation.

[MSDN documentation on Popup control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.popup(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score -4):

Simply show a new window with two buttons. Add property to contain user result.