# Input dialogue popup on mouse click

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-input

I'm trying to make it so when the user clicks on a spot in my canvas, a popup is displayed that allows the user to enter two separate pieces of data. So I need two textblocks and then a way to save the data entered into some variables in the code behind. I've been looking at different tutorials and it's easy making a window with input texblocks. Just not sure how to do it with popups. The addNode_MouseDown method is where I tried adding the popup, since the information entered is going to be about the circle that the user makes when they click on the canvas. Any help would be appreciated.

Here's my code at the moment:

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="CanvasStuff.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Main Window" Height="410" Width="869">
 <Grid Height="387">
    <Label Content="Image" Height="32" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="11,10,0,0"
           Name="selectedFileName" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="137"
           Background="LightGray" BorderBrush="Gray" BorderThickness="1"/>
    <Button Content="Browse File" Height="34" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="154,6,0,0"
            Name="BrowseButton" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="119"
            Foreground="Maroon" FontSize="16" FontFamily="Georgia" Click="BrowseButton_Click" />
    <Button Content="Input Range and Heading" Height="34" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="279,6,0,0"
            Name="InputRangeBearing" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="191"
            Foreground="Maroon" FontSize="16" FontFamily="Georgia" Click="InputButton_Click" />
    <Canvas Margin="0,45,2,8" x:Name="canvas1" MouseDown= "addNode_MouseDown">
    </Canvas>
 </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code behind:

```
namespace CanvasStuff
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for Window1.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void BrowseButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog dlg = new OpenFileDialog();
            dlg.InitialDirectory = "c:\\";
            dlg.Filter = "Image files (*.jpg)|*.jpg|All Files (*.*)|*.*";
            dlg.RestoreDirectory = true;

            if (dlg.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {
                string selectedFileName = dlg.FileName;
                ImageBrush brush = new ImageBrush();
                brush.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri(selectedFileName));
                canvas1.Background = brush;
                BitmapImage bitmap = new BitmapImage();
            }

        }

        private void InputButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please click on known object to enter range and heading of that     object.");
        }

        private void addNode_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            Point currentPoint = new Point();
            if (e.ButtonState == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
                currentPoint = e.GetPosition(this);

            Ellipse ellipse = new Ellipse();

            SolidColorBrush mySolidColorBrush = new SolidColorBrush();

            mySolidColorBrush.Color = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255, 0);
            ellipse.Fill = mySolidColorBrush;
            ellipse.Width = 10;
            ellipse.Height = 10;

            Canvas.SetLeft(ellipse, e.GetPosition(canvas1).X);
            Canvas.SetTop(ellipse, e.GetPosition(canvas1).Y);
            canvas1.Children.Add(ellipse);

        } 

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using the `PopUp` window?

XAML:

```
<Popup Name="errMsg" StaysOpen="False">
<TextBox/>
</Popup>
```

in your code behind:

```
errMsg.IsOpen = true;
```

Or you could either create fully using your code:

[WPF popup window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11499932/)

Reference:

[Popup a User Control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18719977/wpf-how-popup-a-usercontrol)

Comment: Thanks for the response. I looked into PopUp but I found people saying it's not good practice to use it to get input, only for displaying some text. I'll try it out though.

Comment: Okay so, I can use a popup to get one input, but not two because of a "can only have one child" error. For example, I can have an input textbox, but can't have a label next to it. I need to be able to show two labels, and then two textboxes next to them for input. I've tried a new window, but same thing.