# Popup window to get user input

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, window, user-input

I had a similar question here: [Input dialogue popup on mouse click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27111814/input-dialogue-popup-on-mouse-click/27117352#27117352)

So when the user clicks on the canvas, a colored circle is marked where the mouse clicked, and a popup is displayed with two textboxes to get user input. I'm trying to accomplish two things: Instead of a popup, I would like to have a window displayed so the user can move the popup around (right now it's just a white space that sits in the same place). I also would like to add an 'ok' button so that when it's clicked, the two inputs get saved to their respective variables and the window closes.

I've tried adding a  tag after the popup, but I get a xamlparseexception. I'm not sure what to do to make it so the popup is a window. Regarding the input text, I've seen many examples where the user enters text into a textbox and the data is saved to a variable, but nothing on saving it after the textbox window is closed. This is my first wpf application and I'm slowly trying to work through and learn it. Here's the code I have as it currently stands:

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="CanvasStuff.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Main Window" Height="410" Width="869">
  <Grid Height="387">
    <Label Content="Image" Height="32" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="11,10,0,0"
           Name="selectedFileName" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="137"
           Background="LightGray" BorderBrush="Gray" BorderThickness="1"/>
    <Button Content="Browse File" Height="34" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="154,6,0,0"
            Name="BrowseButton" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="119"
            Foreground="Maroon" FontSize="16" FontFamily="Georgia" Click="BrowseButton_Click" />
    <Button Content="Input Range and Heading" Height="34" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="279,6,0,0"
            Name="InputRangeBearing" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="191"
            Foreground="Maroon" FontSize="16" FontFamily="Georgia" Click="InputButton_Click" />
    <Canvas Margin="0,45,2,8" x:Name="canvas1" MouseDown= "addNode_MouseDown">
        <Popup Name="inputPopup" MouseDown="addNode_MouseDown" >
                <Grid Height="150" Background="White" >
                    <Label Content="Range to object (m): " Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="39,28,0,0" Name="label1" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
                    <TextBox x:Name="rangeToObject" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="151,30,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" />
                    <Label Content="Heading to Object (0-360): " Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="39,63,0,0" Name="label2" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
                    <TextBox x:Name="headingToObject" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="151,68,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" />
                </Grid>
        </Popup>
    </Canvas>
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code behind:

```
namespace CanvasStuff
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for Window1.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void BrowseButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog dlg = new OpenFileDialog();
        dlg.InitialDirectory = "c:\\";
        dlg.Filter = "Image files (*.jpg)|*.jpg|All Files (*.*)|*.*";
        dlg.RestoreDirectory = true;

        if (dlg.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            string selectedFileName = dlg.FileName;
            ImageBrush brush = new ImageBrush();
            brush.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri(selectedFileName));
            canvas1.Background = brush;
            BitmapImage bitmap = new BitmapImage();
        }

    }

    private void InputButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please click on known object to enter range and heading of that object.");
    }

    private void addNode_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        Point currentPoint = new Point();
        if (e.ButtonState == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
            currentPoint = e.GetPosition(this);

        Ellipse ellipse = new Ellipse();

        SolidColorBrush mySolidColorBrush = new SolidColorBrush();

        mySolidColorBrush.Color = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255, 0);
        ellipse.Fill = mySolidColorBrush;
        ellipse.Width = 10;
        ellipse.Height = 10;

        Canvas.SetLeft(ellipse, e.GetPosition(canvas1).X);
        Canvas.SetTop(ellipse, e.GetPosition(canvas1).Y);
        canvas1.Children.Add(ellipse);

        inputPopup.IsOpen = true;

    } 

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To clarify, are you saying you'd prefer the popup box to appear as a completely separate window that the user can move around?

It's hard to know how deep to go, if this is your first WPF application. But it looks to me like you're straying into territory where MVVM and Databinding will be a great help to you.

I can strongly recommend that you spend some time getting to grips with the [MVVM pattern](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/165368/WPF-MVVM-Quick-Start-Tutorial), and WPF's databinding paradigm. There are plenty of good tutorials out there.

Once you've got the hang of the basics, I can highly recommend the [MVVM-Light Toolkit](https://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/) to ease the pain of creating ViewModels and ICommands. It also contains a baisc messaging service, to simply communication between Windows and Views.

Sorry, I've not actually answered your question - but hopefully the links will give you some help :)

Comment: Yep that's correct. Right now when the user clicks somewhere on the canvas it's just a white space with the textboxes and labels in there. Thanks for the links, I'll give them a read!